# Excel VBA to copy daily added new data to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've been using Stack Overflow to find solutions to Excel VBA problems a lot, but this is the first time I'm really struggling to find the correct solution. So I guess it's about time I posted my first question here.

I have a worksheet that is refreshed daily from an external source. This source builds a report containing data for the last 2 weeks. I'm importing this data to the worksheet called "data".

The report has a unique identifier per row in column A. That is the value I use to search for new data. Each row also contains the date of when the row was added to the report. This date is in column D and is formatted dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm.

Now I want to make sort of a backup of this data onto the worksheet "backup" since the report only contains data for the last two weeks and I want to build a longer history.

So my code needs to find all rows on the sheet "data" that are not yet present on the sheet "backup" and add the data it finds to the sheet "backup".

I can find lots of solutions that get me close. But what I am struggling with most, is how to loop through the already existing data on worksheet "backup" so that it searches the data worksheet with the values already present in the backup worksheet.

This is what I've got so far:

```
Sub Data_backup()

    Dim data As Worksheet
    Dim backup As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng_totaal As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng_totaal2 As Range
    Dim zoekrng As Range
    Dim zoekmatrix As Range

    Set data = Sheets("data")
    Set backup = Sheets("backup")
    Set rng = data.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0)
    Set rng_totaal = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count)
    Set rng2 = backup.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0)
    Set rng2_totaal = rng2.Resize(rng2.Rows.Count - 1, rng2.Columns.Count)
    Set zoekmatrix = rng_totaal.Columns(1)
    Set zoekrng = rng2_totaal.Columns(1)

    With zoekmatrix
        Set src = .Find("D-2017-0792994", LookIn:=xlValues,      LookAt:=xlWhole).EntireRow
        Set cpy = backup.Range("A1").End(xlDown).EntireRow
        If Not src Is Nothing Then
            cpy.Value = src.Value
        Else
            MsgBox ("ok")
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Now the search value `D-2017-0792994` needs to become dynamic so it can loop through all the cells in column A of the sheet `backup`. And that is where I can't figure it out anymore and really need some help.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Just another approach: Copy all the data (even the duplicates) and then use the remove duplicates feature of excel (on the key column) in the backup sheet.

Comment: How in the world did I not think of that... I got so lost in some fancy pancy macro way that I totally missed this. Thank you for this insight :)

Comment: No worries, sometimes it's hard to see the obvious ;) But just to mention: If speed becomes an issue, it still might be an option to write an algorithm to copy only non duplicate data (can't say which one is faster at the moment without doing some decent testing).

Comment: I don't think speed will be an issue anytime soon. on average the report grows by about 70 rows per working day. For now the duplicate function works well. If the need rises to write a more efficient macro i'll dive into it then.  thnx for your help